# Numpad behaviour constantly changing

Tags: xorg, keyboard

I have a Lenovo G550 laptop with Ubuntu 12.10 installed and I have a problem with the Numpad/Num Lock behaviour (standard Hungarian layout). Sometimes when I press Home (key 7) it types 7 (or press End it types 1, etc.) so I need to press Num Lock to change the numpad status (for eg. to On or Off). But after a while I need to press Num Lock again cause Home key types 7 again. So regardless of the Num Lock status my keyboard sometimes behaves differently from time to time. What do I need to set to make the Num Lock behaviour constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click in your user name in the corner of your screen.
2. Select 'System Settings'
3. Region and Language
4. In the 'Layouts' tab click 'Options...'
5. Look for 'Miscellaneous Compatibility Options' group. Check if the 'Shift with numeric keypad works as in MS Windows' option is activated.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately these options are not available in 15.04 anymore.